# failure to install modeest packages in RStudio in Ubuntu

Tags: r, ubuntu

I am a bit new to R and I am trying to install the modeest package but I get this error:

```
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘gss’
* removing ‘/home/miguel/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.2/gss’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘gss’ had non-zero exit status
* installing *source* package ‘rmutil’ ...
** package ‘rmutil’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** using staged installation
** libs
sh: 1: make: not found
Warning in system(cmd) : error in running command
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘rmutil’
* removing ‘/home/miguel/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.2/rmutil’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘rmutil’ had non-zero exit status
* installing *source* package ‘clue’ ...
** package ‘clue’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** using staged installation
** libs
sh: 1: make: not found
Warning in system(cmd) : error in running command
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘clue’
* removing ‘/home/miguel/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.2/clue’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘clue’ had non-zero exit status
ERROR: dependency ‘gss’ is not available for package ‘fBasics’
* removing ‘/home/miguel/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.2/fBasics’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘fBasics’ had non-zero exit status
ERROR: dependency ‘rmutil’ is not available for package ‘stable’
* removing ‘/home/miguel/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.2/stable’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘stable’ had non-zero exit status
ERROR: dependency ‘clue’ is not available for package ‘statip’
* removing ‘/home/miguel/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.2/statip’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘statip’ had non-zero exit status
ERROR: dependencies ‘fBasics’, ‘stable’, ‘statip’ are not available for package ‘modeest’
* removing ‘/home/miguel/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.2/modeest’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘modeest’ had non-zero exit status

The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘/tmp/RtmpFXPprD/downloaded_packages’
```

I tried this but it doesn't work, it keeps coming up with the same thing.

```
sudo rm -rf /home/miguel/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.2/gss
```

I'm using Ubuntu 22.04. And R version 4.2.1.

Comment: The issue here is that your system cannot compile packages from source because it is missing the `make` command (and likely other essential tools). Try `sudo apt-get install build-essential`.

Comment: Thank you very much but it still doesn't work. Now I get this error: ```/bin/bash: line 1: gfortran: orden not found
make: *** [/usr/lib/R/etc/Makeconf:191: cdennewton.o] Error 127``` and next the same of the first. I think I just need install gfortran maybe.

Comment: I don't know what "orden" means, but perhaps gfortran is also not installed, so try `sudo apt-get install gfortran`.

Comment: Still doesn't work, I get this error message:
```/usr/bin/ld: can't find -llapack: File or directory does not exist
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lblas: File or directory does not exist
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [/usr/share/R/share/make/shlib.mk:10: gss.so] Error 1```

Comment: [See if this helps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57762660/r-cannot-find-llapack-cannot-find-lblas). You just need to keep Googling these errors, identifying the missing libraries and installing until it works.